# Python, CIFAR-10のデータを読み込む方法

Tags: python

以下のサイトで提供されているカラー画像8000万枚のデータセットCIFAR-10を読み込みたいのですがいくつか他のサイトにあるものを試しているのですがどれもうまくいかず、ご存知の方いらしましたら教えて頂きたいです。

データ元 
https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html

以下読み込むコード

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import os

def unpickle(file):
    fo = open(file, 'rb')
    dict = pickle.load(fo)
    fo.close()
    return dict

def conv_data2image(data):
    return np.rollaxis(data.reshape((3,32,32)),0,3)

def get_cifar10(folder):
    tr_data = np.empty((0,32*32*3))
    tr_labels = np.empty(1)
    '''
    32x32x3
    '''
    for i in range(1,6):
        fname = os.path.join(folder, "%s%d" % ("data_batch_", i))
        data_dict = unpickle(fname)
        if i == 1:
            tr_data = data_dict['data']
            tr_labels = data_dict['labels']
        else:
            tr_data = np.vstack((tr_data, data_dict['data']))
            tr_labels = np.hstack((tr_labels, data_dict['labels']))

    data_dict = unpickle(os.path.join(folder, 'test_batch'))
    te_data = data_dict['data']
    te_labels = np.array(data_dict['labels'])

    bm = unpickle(os.path.join(folder, 'batches.meta'))
    label_names = bm['label_names']
    return tr_data, tr_labels, te_data, te_labels, label_names

if __name__ == '__main__':
    datapath = "./data/cifar-10-batches-py"

    tr_data10, tr_labels10, te_data10, te_labels10, label_names10 = get_cifar10(datapath)
```

以下エラー

> "C:\…\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe"
>   "C:/…/PycharmProjects/Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual
>   Recognition/input_cifar.py" Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/…/PycharmProjects/Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual
>   Recognition/input_cifar.py", line 41, in  tr_data10,
>   tr_labels10, te_data10, te_labels10, label_names10 =
>   get_cifar10(datapath) File "C:/…/PycharmProjects/Convolutional Neural
>   Networks for Visual Recognition/input_cifar.py", line 22, in
>   get_cifar10 data_dict = unpickle(fname) File
>   "C:/…/PycharmProjects/Convolutional Neural Networks for Visual
>   Recognition/input_cifar.py", line 7, in unpickle dict =
>   pickle.load(fo) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte
>   0x8b in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

使用のPythonVersionは3.x系でしょうか？
7行目を以下にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

```
dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='latin-1')
```

または

```
u = pickle._Unpickler(fo)
u.encoding = 'latin1'
dict = u.load()
```

同様エラーのポスト
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305790/pickle-incompatability-of-numpy-arrays-between-python-2-and-3

Comment: 即時ご回答頂きありがとうございます。ご指摘頂いた内容を修正してみたところエラーは消えたのですが思わしい結果がでず困っております。以下のサイトによれば`In [1]: %run input_cifar.py
In [2]: tr_data10.shape
Out[2]: (50000, 3072)
In [3]: tr_labels10.shape
Out[3]: (50000,)
In [4]: te_data10.shape
Out[4]: (10000, 3072)
In [5]: te_labels10.shape
Out[5]: (10000,)
In [6]: label_names10
Out[6]: 
['airplane',
 'automobile',
 'bird',
 'cat',
 'deer',
 'dog',
 'frog',
 'horse',
 'ship',
 'truck']`が実行結果だとおもうのですが、何も出力されません。サイト:[http://qiita.com/supersaiakujin/items/5e9d2b2850e256f99982]

Comment: ご提示のサイトはscript内で結果を出力しているのではなく、script内で変数に値を格納してから、手打ちで変数の値を表示しています。script内にprint文をを仕込むか、pythonのshellを立ち上げ後に参考サイトのように%run input_cifar.py; tr_data10.shape; tr_labels10.shape; te_data10.shape; te_labels10.shape; label_names10; と実行していってください(;はEnterの意)

Comment: ありがとうございます。うまくいきました